# Inserting checkbox values into mysql database with different column

Tags: php, checkbox

So far I have tried and implemented this code. I want to Insert the checkbox value with different column, so that I come to know How of them having Tablet,Pc,Labtop
See my code and guide me.

```
<form name="f1" action="simple.php" method="post"/>
Name:<input type="text" name="name" value=""/><br/>
Are you having <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="pc"/>pc &nbsp&nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="tablet" />Tablet
                 <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="ios" />Ios
                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name=$_POST['name'];
$check=$_POST['check'];
echo $name."<br/>";
echo $check."<br/>";
print_r($check);
         $i=0; 
         $val='';
            foreach($check as $a)
                {

                       $val.=$a[$i]; 

                       $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO carrying (name,pc,tablet,ios) VALUES ('".$name."','".$check[$i]."')");
                     //  mysql_query($query);
                $i++;  
                } 
}
```

In database Column I have created like this i want like this format only:

```
---------------------------------        
|cid | name | pc  | tablet | ios|
---------------------------------
|1   |kodi  | pc  | tablet      |
---------------------------------
|2   |siva  | pc  |             |
---------------------------------
```

Comment: is that my question is clear for all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your database structure like this - it should probably be:

```
$pc = null;
if (array_search('pc', $check) !== false) {
    $pc = 'pc';
}
$tablet = null;
if (array_search('tablet', $check) !== false) {
    $tablet = 'tablet';
}
$ios = null;
if (array_search('ios', $check) !== false) {
    $ios = 'ios';
}

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO carrying (name, pc, tablet, ios) VALUES ('".$name."','".$pc."','".$tablet."','".$ios."')");
```

There are a few problems with the code in terms of SQL injection. IF you are not using a PHP framework you should consider at least using a database abstraction layer like [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) so that you can do things like this (from http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.db-common.execute.php):

```
$sth = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

$data = array(1, 'one', 'en');
$db->execute($sth, $data);
```

Comment: foreach($check as $a)
 {
 $pc = null;
if (array_search('pc', $check) !== false) {
    $pc = 'pc';
}
$tablet = null;
if (array_search('tablet', $check) !== false) {
    $tablet = 'tablet';
}
$ios = null;
if (array_search('ios', $check) !== false) {
    $ios = 'ios';
}

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO carrying (name, pc, tablet, ios) VALUES ('".$name."','".$pc."','".$tablet."','".$ios."')");
}Than you for reply, i have implemented the array_search, it is working fine,but how we do for this type of requirement in plain  php and mysql for checkbox with different column

Comment: This /will/ save it to the database with different checkbox results in different columns.